# Size of the structure with padding

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, structure

I have the following structure . Where the size is calculated on the side. The size of the structure should be 30Bytes after padding . But the size is 28 . How is the structure size 28?

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct a
{
    char t;      //1 byte+7 padding byte      Total = 8bytes
    double d;    //8 bytes                    Total = 16bytes
    short s;     //2 bytes                    Total = 18Bytes
    char arr[12];//12 bytes 8+8+4+12=32.      Total = 30Bytes
};
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(struct a));  // O/p = 28bytes
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What cpu architecture and ABI? Alignment requirements are implementation-specific.

Comment: @Cicada: Compiler cannot and will not *rearrange* structs. It can add padding, but not change the field order.

Comment: @Cicada this is not wording, a lot of people think the implementation can reorder the structure members.

Comment: I agree that the word "rearrange" was unclear and perhaps misleading. Actually the amount of rearrangement a compiler is free to do is very small; the only freedom it has is the freedom to put arbitrary fixed padding that can serve no purpose. Everything else is restricted by the rules about structs which have the same initial set of members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `offsetof` to know the actual padding after each structure member:

```
#include <stddef.h>

printf("Padding after t: %zu\n", 
    offsetof(struct a, d) - sizeof (((struct a *) 0)->t));

printf("Padding after d: %zu\n",
    offsetof(struct a, s) - offsetof(struct a, d)
    - sizeof (((struct a *) 0)->d));

printf("Padding after s: %zu\n",
    offsetof(struct a, arr) - offsetof(struct a, s)
    - sizeof (((struct a *) 0)->s));

printf("Padding after arr: %zu\n",
      sizeof(struct a) - offsetof(struct a, arr)
      - sizeof (((struct a *) 0)->arr));
```

As `R.` wrote, you are probably on a `32-bit` system where alignment of `double` is 4 bytes instead of 8.

Answer (score 4):

You are miscalculating the byte padding. This thing depends upon the compiler options and other stuff. You should look into the pragma's pack directive to show you the correct value of padding. For instance:

```
#pragma pack(show)
```

should show you the byte padding via the means of a warning. You can also set it explicitly to tailor your code to your needs. Look it up on the msdn. Here is the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think it's aligning on 32-bit boundaries, not 64. How about this:

```
struct a
{
    char t;      //1 byte+3 padding bytes     Total = 4bytes
    double d;    //8 bytes                    Total = 12bytes
    short s;     //2 bytes+2 padding bytes    Total = 16Bytes
    char arr[12];//12 bytes 4+8+4+12=28.      Total = 28Bytes
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're building on a 32-bit architecture where `double` does not have 8-byte alignment requirement, in which case the alignments become:

```
struct a
{
    char t;      //1 byte+3 padding byte      Total = 4bytes
    double d;    //8 bytes                    Total = 12bytes
    short s;     //2 bytes                    Total = 14Bytes
    char arr[12];//12 bytes +2 padding bytes  Total = 28Bytes
};
```

Comment: These are also the paddings I have on my 32-bit machine.

Answer (score 1):

In this case for each structure member, memory is given in multiples of 4bytes,

char t - 4bytes, double d - 8bytes, short s - 4bytes and char arr[12] - 12bytes.

total 4(char)+8(double)+4(short)+12(char array)=28bytes

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the char is followed by 3 bytes padding (so the double starts on a 4-byte boundary), and the short is followed by 2 bytes padding as well.

But ... why not print the member offsets to see for yourself?